# How to convert a unichar value to an NSString in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I've got an international character stored in a unichar variable. This character does not come from a file or url. The variable itself only stores an unsigned short(0xce91) which is in UTF-8 format and translates to the greek capital letter 'A'. I'm trying to put that character into an NSString variable but i fail miserably.

I've tried 2 different ways both of which unsuccessful:

```
unichar greekAlpha = 0xce91; //could have written greekAlpha = 'Α' instead.

NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Greek Alpha: %C", greekAlpha];
```

No good. I get some weird chinese characters. As a sidenote this works perfectly with english characters.

Then I also tried this:

```
NSString *byteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&greekAlpha
                                                length:sizeof(unichar)
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But this doesn't work either. 
I'm obviously doing something terribly wrong, but I don't know what.
Can someone help me please ? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can format the code for nicer formatting by pressing the little button saying 101010 in the editor toolbar.

Comment: Are you sure `unichar` is the right data type to be using here? Storing UTF-8 data in a type intended for UTF-16 smells wrong. As noted by Jon Jardine, there are UTF-8 characters longer than 16 bits... Could you just use NSString for the single char too (`NSString greekAlpha = @"Α"` and then use %@ in `stringWithFormat`)?

Comment: 0xce91 is actually the Unicode for "HANGUL SYLLABLE KAEG", so I can't figure out why you would expect to get an Alpha character from that.  You seem to be confused by LATIN SMALL LETTER ALPHA being 0xc9, 0x91 in UTF-8. Totally different encoding. The Unicode value is 0x0251.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `0xce91` is in the UTF-8 format and `%C` expects it to be in UTF-16 a simple solution like the one above won't work. For `stringWithFormat:@"%C"` to work you need to input `0x391` which is the UTF-16 unicode.

In order to create a string from the UTF-8 encoded unichar you need to first split the unicode into it's octets and then use `initWithBytes:length:encoding`.

```
unichar utf8char = 0xce91; 
char chars[2];
int len = 1;

if (utf8char > 127) {
    chars[0] = (utf8char >> 8) & (1 << 8) - 1;
    chars[1] = utf8char & (1 << 8) - 1; 
    len = 2;
} else {
    chars[0] = utf8char;
}

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:chars
                                            length:len 
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I realized the same after I looked closer at the link I posted. I updated my answer with this information and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for! So then, my bits were scrambled :). 

Even though I'm a new member to this site I've been using it for quite some time now(for c# stuff mostly, just getting my feet wet with objective-c) and I find it amazing how far some people will go to help others. Once again, thank you! :)

Comment: @Terry - StackOverflow is a counterexample to the rule that programmers are lazy. An oddity that arises is that 99% of Linux hasn't ever been code reviewed, but nearly every Question, Answer, and Comment on SO has been reviewed, edited, voted on, and discussed. The very features of SO have had the same done on MetaStackOverflow.

Answer (score 55):

```
unichar greekAlpha = 0x0391;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&greekAlpha length:1];
```

And now you can incorporate that NSString into another in any way you like. Do note, however, that it is now legal to type a Greek alpha directly into an NSString literal.

Comment: This worked perfectly for just one character. Not sure why this was downvoted. +1

Comment: Why is this NOT the answer?

Comment: unichar is an unsigned short... 16-bit only.  If you have a 32-bit unicode like the emojis, it won't work.  e.g. 0x1F347

Comment: @Billy the problem as posed was not about an emoji, it was about a greek alpha.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is great but doesn't account for UTF-8 characters longer than 16 bits, e.g. the ellipsis symbol - 0xE2,0x80,0xA6. Here's a tweak to the code:

```
if (utf8char > 65535) {
   chars[0] = (utf8char >> 16) & 255;
   chars[1] = (utf8char >> 8) & 255;
   chars[2] = utf8char & 255; 
   chars[3] = 0x00;
} else if (utf8char > 127) {
    chars[0] = (utf8char >> 8) & 255;
    chars[1] = utf8char & 255; 
    chars[2] = 0x00;
} else {
    chars[0] = utf8char;
    chars[1] = 0x00;
}
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:chars] autorelease];
```

Note the different string initialisation method which doesn't require a length parameter.

Comment: but 'unichar' is a 16-bit type, so `utf8char` could not hold a value longer than 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm for UTF-8 encoding on a single character:

```
if (utf8char<0x80){ 
    chars[0] = (utf8char>>0)  & (0x7F | 0x00);
    chars[1] = 0x00;
    chars[2] = 0x00;
    chars[3] = 0x00;
}
else if (utf8char<0x0800){
    chars[0] = (utf8char>>6)  & (0x1F | 0xC0);
    chars[1] = (utf8char>>0)  & (0x3F | 0x80);
    chars[2] = 0x00;
    chars[3] = 0x00;
}
else if (utf8char<0x010000) {
    chars[0] = (utf8char>>12) & (0x0F | 0xE0);
    chars[1] = (utf8char>>6)  & (0x3F | 0x80);
    chars[2] = (utf8char>>0)  & (0x3F | 0x80);
    chars[3] = 0x00;
}
else if (utf8char<0x110000) {
    chars[0] = (utf8char>>18) & (0x07 | 0xF0);
    chars[1] = (utf8char>>12) & (0x3F | 0x80);
    chars[2] = (utf8char>>6)  & (0x3F | 0x80);
    chars[3] = (utf8char>>0)  & (0x3F | 0x80);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above is the moral equivalent of `unichar foo = 'abc';`.

The problem is that `'Α'` doesn't map to a single byte in the "execution character set" (I'm assuming UTF-8) which is "implementation-defined" in [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §6.4.4.4 10:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.

One way is to make `'ab'` equal to `'a'<<8|b`. Some Mac/iOS system headers rely on this for things like `OSType`/`FourCharCode`/[FourCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC); the only one in iOS that comes to mind is CoreVideo pixel formats. This is, however, unportable.

If you really want a `unichar` literal, you can try `L'A'` (technically it's a `wchar_t` literal, but on OS X and iOS, `wchar_t` is typically UTF-16 so it'll work for things inside the BMP). However, it's far simpler to just use `@"Α"` (which works as long as you set the source character encoding correctly) or `@"\u0391"` (which has worked since at least the iOS 3 SDK).