# iOS Convert Hex value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

How to convert hexadecimal value into emoji icons , I have a string like below

```
NSString *myVal = @"1F61E";
```

how can i convert this text to display it as emoji charrcaters?

I have found that value [from this link](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/emoticons.html)
Please let me know, i am really stuck-up with this issue

**`Updated`**

```
NSString *utf8String1 = @"1F61E";
NSString *a = [self convert:utf8String1];
NSLog(@"%@ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&",a);


-(NSString*)convert:(NSString*)decoded{

    unichar unicodeValue = (unichar) strtol([decoded UTF8String], NULL, 16);
    char buffer[2];
    int len = 1;

    if (unicodeValue > 127) {
        buffer[0] = (unicodeValue >> 8) & (1 << 8) - 1;
        buffer[1] = unicodeValue & (1 << 8) - 1; 
        len = 2;
    } else {
        buffer[0] = unicodeValue;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



}
```

Comment: Check this answer on SO which explains exactly this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code point that you are trying to encode does not fit in 16 bits. Therefore you need to use UTF-32 encoding:

```
NSScanner *scan = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"1F61E"];
unsigned int val;
[scan scanHexInt:&val];
char cc[4];
cc[3] = (val >> 0) & 0xFF;
cc[2] = (val >> 8) & 0xFF;
cc[1] = (val >> 16) & 0xFF;
cc[0] = (val >> 24) & 0xFF;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]
    initWithBytes:cc
           length:4
         encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"[%@]", s);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.how can i convert my variable to this format 0x00, 0x01, 0cf6, 0x1e? pls let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, pls can you explain me how it works

Comment: @user198725878 Sure! `NSScanner` converts your hex value to a 4-byte unsigned int, four `>>` and `& 0xFF` operations "cut out" individual 8-bit portions into a 4-byte array of `char`, and finally a string is constructed from these four bytes with a `NSUTF32StringEncoding` flag, which says that each string character is encoded as a four-byte UNICODE code point.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to convert it to it's numerical value:

```
unichar unicodeValue = (unichar) strtol([input UTF8String], NULL, 16);
```

Then, following from the rules of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c):

```
char buffer[2];
int len = 1;

if (unicodeValue > 127) {
    buffer[0] = (unicodeValue >> 8) & (1 << 8) - 1;
    buffer[1] = unicodeValue & (1 << 8) - 1; 
    len = 2;
} else {
    buffer[0] = unicodeValue;
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You now have your UTF-8 Formatted string!

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.will this result of that nsstring would be emoji icons? or do i need to still do anything to get displayed.pls let me know

Comment: @user198725878 sorry, I don't have a device to test this on, you'd have to try for yourself!

Comment: when i tried printing return nsstring value using nslog it just displays me as"(null)"pls let me know

Comment: when i tried printing return nsstring value using nslog it just displays me as"(null)"pls let me know

Comment: @user198725878 is it possible that you can simply append that as a char using \u1F61E in your string? It'd be much easier than the strtol approach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9370/discussion-between-richard-j-ross-iii-and-user198725878)