# how to convert Nsstring value into Hexdecimal in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hello i'm beginner in iOS In one of my activity I have NSString and want to convert into Hexdecimal format

```
    NSString  *str= 131003112444371;

long long decimalRepresentation = 131003112444371;
    NSLog(@"date %llx",decimalRepresentation);

    NSLog(@"Hex value of char is 0x%02llx",decimalRepresentation);
```

I am using this I then get result 0x772589fb51d3 and I want to extract this no 772589fb51d3 
When I am using these line for this ....

```
      NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu",decimalRepresentation];

      NSLog(@"str %@",str1);


    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0x"];
    str1 = [[str1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:doNotWant]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", str1); // => foobarbazfoo
```

but this line again convert this hexdecimal value into string I don't extract this value 
 0x772589fb51d3  as 772589fb51d3 .please help me....
Thanks In advance

Comment: [Please go through this Below link may be this will help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888456/ios-convert-hex-value

Comment: I want to convert nsstring into hexdecimal format

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Have you tried looking at SO before posting your question?

Comment: I already checked ...If u have any answer then give otherwise don't waste time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried like this:-

```
NsString  *str= 131003112444371;

long long decimalRepresentation = 131003112444371;
    NSLog(@"date %llx",decimalRepresentation);

    NSLog(@"Hex value of char is 0x%02llx",decimalRepresentation);
```

//just replaced llu to llx

```
   NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llx",decimalRepresentation];

      NSLog(@"str %@",str1);
```

And the output i got here is **772589fb51d3**

Comment: Is this is only your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

One Possible solution of this question:

```
+(NSString*)hexFromStr:(NSString*)str
{
NSData* nsData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char* data = [nsData bytes];
NSUInteger len = nsData.length;
NSMutableString* hex = [NSMutableString string];
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)[hex appendFormat:@"%02X", data[i]];
return hex;
}
```