# Why can't I create a string in lldb?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata, lldb

Specifically, why doesn't this work?

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithCharacters:(char*)[data bytes] length:(int)[data length]]
error: Couldn't execute function; result was eExecutionDiscarded
```

There are other questions dealing with dumping NSData, but I thought this would be a better solution.  I was surprised it didn't work.  Just trying to understand why.

Comment: I managed something similar with this: `[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:(char*)[@"James" dataUsingEncoding:4] encoding:4] autorelease]` The `4` is NSUTF8StringEncoding, enum not available in lldb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it is expecting a `unichar`? Try this.

[How to convert a unichar value to an NSString in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c)